# Slide In and Out Gui Using Buttons Doesn't Work

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm using Roblox Studio and the only language I'm familiar with is Java. I created 2 buttons called "open" and "close", and a frame including images and text called "menu". I'm trying to make it so when you click on the open button, the menu and the close button slide out while the open button disappears—opposite happens when you click on the close button. My code doesn't work at all and I'm not sure why, any feedback would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have use the dot "." to get/set the properties of an UI element. In this case,

```lua
buttonC = UDmi2.new() -- this sets the variable to UDmi2 position
buttonC.Position = UDmi2.new() -- set the position of buttonC
buttonO.Position = UDmi2.new();
```

Also, in line 19 you are missing the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Fixed line 19. Not sure what you mean by `buttonC = UDmi2.new()` but it gives me an error saying "unknown global UDmi2" so I tried changing my `local buttonO = gui.open` to `local buttonO = gui.open.new()` but that didn't seem to fix anything. I also added `buttonO.Position = UDim2.new()` with my coordinates since I didn't have that before (the other positions are under my variables) but nothing changed

Comment: You need to put the location inside the UDmi2.new() for example: UDmi2.new(0.5,0,0.5,0)

Comment: I did, I added my coordinates inside the parenthesis just like that. Also, it's not UDmi2 it's UDim2